# How to get current page in MuPDF?

Tags: android, mupdf

I need to go to the same page on a PDF document after screen change. I have found how to navigate to page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220441/navigating-to-a-specific-page-with-the-mupdf-android-library) but I failed to get the current page number.

I have found some codes regarding this in MuPDF library but couldn't call it from main activity. In PageView class (MuPDFPageView extends PageView):

```
public int getPage() {
    return mPageNumber;
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to call this from main activity. I tried something like this:

```
final MuPDFPageView pageView = new MuPDFPageView(getApplicationContext(), filePickerSupport, core, parentSize, sharedHqBm);
int i = pageView.getPage();
```

But failed to fill the parameters in. Anybody has a better or easier way to get the current page number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within MuPDFActivity, you can call:

mDocView.getDisplayedViewIndex()

and that will return you the current page number.